# Numerical method to find $\alpha_0$ where $\alpha x=cosh x$ has exactly one solution

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Numerical method to find $\alpha_0$ where $\alpha x=cosh x$ has exactly one solution.

When doing catenoid problems, I came across these three cases:
Different $\alpha$ may lead to 0 or 1, or 2 solutions to $\alpha x=cosh x$, and now I want to find the critical solution where $\alpha_0$ leads to exactly one solution to that function.

I haven't learned numerical analysis and optimization. Could anyone give me some idea of what methods I should use? I'll look it up then. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a standard calculus problem. You want two curves whose single intersection is a tangent, in other words the system of equations $$\begin{cases} \alpha x = \cosh x \\ \alpha = \sinh x \end{cases} \implies \alpha \sinh^{-1}\alpha = \sqrt{1+\alpha^2}$$

Comment: If you look for a simple approximation, you could use $$x \sinh (x)-\cosh (x) \sim \frac{457 x^4+2844 x^2-5040}{11 x^4-324 x^2+5040}$$ Make the numerator equal to $0$; this is a quadratic equation in $x^2$. The result will be in an error of $2.13\times 10^{-5}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Probably the simplest is to search for the minimum of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\cosh (x)}{x}-\alpha$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\frac{x \sinh (x)-\cosh (x)}{x^2}$$ So, we look for the zero of function
$$g(x)=x \sinh (x)-\cosh (x)$$
By inspection, the root is between $1$ and $1.5$.

So, start any Newton like method to get it and then deduce $\alpha$.